# broadcomm wireless driver install problem

Tags: 12.04

I have tried to install the broadcom drivers according to this thread ( [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers) )

when I try |I get this....

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

so i followed this thread to remove the lock ( http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1015279 )

when I use the command... sudo sudo dpkg --configure -a ... my termanal freezes...
here is the terminal output up to were it freezes...

ryan@ryan-GC670AAR-ABA-a6120n:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -aSetting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.2) ...
Removing old bcmwl-6.20.155.1+bdcom DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.20.155.1+bdcom

### Kernel:  3.8.0-31-generic (i686)

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.8.0-31-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

---

Deleting module version: 6.20.155.1+bdcom

### completely from the DKMS tree.

Done.
Loading new bcmwl-6.20.155.1+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.8.0-31-generic
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.8.0-31-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.8.0-31-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.

please hepl me,  i am not a complete noob but also not really great at ubuntu

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason you could no download is that you had two different download processes making requests at the same time. Make sure that Ubuntu is not trying to update when you use either the software center or synaptic. Reboot and then check first to see if Ubuntu has updates for you. Update then close the updater down. Now you can use either synaptic or the software center. Just do not try to use them both at the same time.